# p:selectOneMenu list not displaying properly

Tags: css, primefaces, xhtml

I have a p:selectOneMenu in xhtml. But the list is not displaying properly. The list have near to 70 items. When I click on the selectOneMenu, the list populate upwards instead without scrollbar and I can't see all the items.

```
<td valign="top"><p:selectOneMenu id="fr1022_combo_box_ctpy"
      value="#{pc_Fr1022.w_facility.ctpy}" styleClass="selectOneMenu">
      <f:selectItems value="#{pc_Fr1022.w_facility.facilityCtpyList}"></f:selectItems>
  </p:selectOneMenu>
</td>
```

Comment: `the list populate upwards instead without scrollbar` Upwards? I guess you have sometihing tough below this combo box.Please share all the code of page or div.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way you have used f:selectItems is incorrect.
It should be

```
<f:selectItems value="#{pc_Fr1022.w_facility.facilityCtpyList}" var="facility"
                       itemLabel="#{facility.name}" itemValue="#{facility.value}" />
```

HTH

Comment: Sorry, I meant grouping by Light Colours and Dark Colours (i.e.
Light Colours (green, yellow, orange)
Dark Colours (brown, black, blue)

Comment: I think if it is a list of Strings and the value is of type String either, it is no problem how hahagal used f:selectItems.